Permutations Doubt: How many $5$-digit whole numbers with no $0$s are divisible by $6$?
I came across this combinatorics question that was quite interesting, as in methods to solve this.
How many $5$-digit whole numbers with no $0$s are divisible by $6$?
First, I found the number of $5$-digit numbers which are even, and then divided this by $3$, as $1$ in $3$ even numbers are divisible by $6$. This gives the correct answer of $8748$.
But, if I go another way and find the number of $5$-digit numbers which are divisible by $3$, and divide this by $2$, (because $1$ in $2$ numbers divisible by 3 are even, and thus, divisible by $6$), I get a different answer.
Is there something I am missing here?
P.S. Yes, I know there is already a question that is the same as this, but I have a different doubt.

“1 in 3 even numbers are divisible by 6”, “1  in 2 numbers divisible by 3 are even”. Why are these statements true for the numbers without $0$s?

What is your "different answer"?

The fraction of 5-digit (even, without 0s) numbers divisible by $3$ is a third, but this requires an argument (eg consider the leading digit mod $3$).

Now I see my mistake - by excluding $0$, the number of five digit numbers divisible by 3 does not suit to the method of dividing by 2. Thank you for the clarification.

Now I see my mistake - by excluding $0$, the number of five digit numbers divisible by $3$ does not suit to the method of dividing by $2$.
